# How do I convert java objects to xml using JAXB without using annotation?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, maven, jaxb

I tried the solutions given online but none of them work. 
Tools used :
Hibernate
Maven
Eclipse IDE
JAXB
JSP
HTML

I have several bean classes. I have mapped them to the schema as well using hbm xmls.. I am looking to convert the objects to xml and store it in an xml file. Please help me out with an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking that rather than loading from the DB on server restart, I could load from the local file!! (as the data in the db updates less often) that's where I got to learn about the XStream Library, and it's so simple that I could convert any java object to XML and back.

[**Detail**](http://www.journaldev.com/1234/jaxb-tutorial-example-to-convert-object-to-xml-and-xml-to-object)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. The XStream library indeed did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

*without annotations* how do you plan to bind data?

XML is a pure structured language. So, if you are marshaling any object, you need to also tell the structure.

So, if you don't want to put annotations you have to let java know the structure using XSD.

Check [this](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/jaxb-and-marshalunmarshal-schema.html) example for using XML Schema Definition.

If you are more interested in finding a simpler solution for marshalling you can try [XMLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) or if you are comfortable with [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/), you can pick any one implementation.